# Ajax response data in .net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, response

I have a asp .net web page and a button in it. I'm calling an ajax method in the button click event as follows

```
 $("#btnTest").click(function () {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: 'test2.aspx',
                     success: function (data) {
                         alert( data);

                     },
                     error: function (data) {
                         alert("In error  ");

                     }
                 });
             });
```

In success part alert( data) Im getting the html code of the page test2.aspx (which one I have given in ajax url).

In test2.aspx.cs code is given as below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        jsonTest();
    }

    public List<string> jsonTest()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("aa");
        list.Add("bb");
        list.Add("cc");
        return list;        
    }
```

Why this data in 'list' is not coming as response data in ajax?

Comment: You just call the jsonTest function, without outputting the result to the page it seems?

Comment: where u attach resposne? you are just returing value to nowhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Response.Write() method for that purpose

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("data to be returned");
}
```

Or try to write static webmethods in aspx page. Those methods can be call from ajax

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return data from aspx to ajax. try this

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(list);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
```

This will help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a normal page method from jQuery.
You need to create a `web-method` to access that from jQuery.
Here is a good link regarding how to call a page method
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

Use like this..

```
 $("#btnTest").click(function () {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: 'test2.aspx',
                     success: function (data) {
                         alert( data.d[0]);
                         alert( data.d[1]);
                         alert( data.d[2]);

                     },
                     error: function (data) {
                         alert("In error  ");

                     }
                 });
             });
```